# Live reload and asp.net vNext on OSX

Tags: macos, mono, asp.net-core

How do you get the command "k kestrel" to live-reload (one of the advantage of asp.net vNext) on MacOSX?

Following "k -h", it looks like the command is "k --watch kestrel", however, it do not reload when I make a change into my sample HelloMvc Controller.

Comment: I answered a similar question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26381414/2528440

Comment: @AndersNS does not answer the question for OSX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment, according to David Fowler, there is a bug in Mono that prohibits detecting file changes. However, a new FileSystemWatcher was supposed to be merged recently so this might work soon!

Comment: Can you find a link to the source for this? Would help to know if it's still a problem! Thanks.

Comment: you could try to ask @davidfowl on twitter or on jabbr.net

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/c82a2e507496a5e23d44a94383406ec2b7d5492a

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this problem by following the suggested solution posted by [miguellira](https://github.com/miguellira) on this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/508

I skipped the first the the second steps, I simply changed my ~/.bash_profile by adding the following:

```
alias dnu="brew switch mono 4.1.0 && dnu"

code () {
  brew switch mono 4.0.1
  if [[ $# = 0 ]]
  then
    open -a "Visual Studio Code"
  else
    [[ $1 = /* ]] && F="$1" || F="$PWD/${1#./}"
    open -a "Visual Studio Code" --args "$F"
  fi
}

export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER=enabled
```

Regarding the bash_profile, if you don't know how to change it (or create it in case you don't have it yet) have a look on this link: https://discussions.apple.com/message/19065947#19065947