# ASP.Net 5 (vNext) incremental build from the command line

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm learning about ASP.Net 5 and I have read several times that a key goal for vNext is to support a Roslyn based incremental build model providing an edit, save, refresh browser workflow. I've seen examples of people running vNext apps in Visual Studio through IIS Express and then changing source files and refreshing the browser to see changes immediately without a manual build step.

However, I have not seen any examples of the same workflow outside of Visual Studio. Another goal of vNext seems to be to support command line/text editor development on platforms other than windows. I've seen examples of people running vNext apps in OS X/Linux on Kestrel from the command line but when I try this the incremental build doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible to do incremental build outside of VS using command line tools?

I also note command line tools like "kpm build" which perform a manual build. Is the idea that incremental/dynamic build is a development time only feature and you would perform a kpm build to produce binaries on disk before deploying the app?

Comment: Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26381414/2528440